# Footbib package error

Tags: natbib, footbib

I am trying to cite the reference in the footnotes of my document using the `footbib` package.

I receive the following error:

> footbib.sty:92: Package footbib Error: the output routine of LaTeX changed

I am using few packages in order to reduce the problem with the `footbib` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4, oneside]{book}

%\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{alltt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[oneside, citeonce(chapter)]{footbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

 @article{Panebianco-2011a,
    Author = {M. PANEBIANCO},
    Date-Added = {2016-12-26 18:20:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-12-26 21:32:38 +0000},
    Pages = {p. 336},
    Title = {Diritto Internazionale Pubblico},
    Volume = {III ed., Editoriale Scientifica, Napoli},
    Year = {2011}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]\footcite{Panebianco-2011a}

\end{document}
```

The reference used is

```
@article{Panebianco-2011a,
    Author = {M. PANEBIANCO},
    Date-Added = {2016-12-26 18:20:51 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-12-26 21:32:38 +0000},
    Pages = {p. 336},
    Title = {Diritto Internazionale Pubblico},
    Volume = {III ed., Editoriale Scientifica, Napoli},
    Year = {2011}}
```

I have tried to use the `biblatex` package but the errors even increase.

A workaround is to use the `biblatex` package with the option style equal `style=authortitle` citing using the command `\autocite`. But this option is less efficient with respect to the use of `footbib` package.

Last point, I'd like to change the counter from square brackets `[1]` to normal parenthesis `(1)`.

[image]

Comment: Since your question is not about `biblatex` I have removed that tag. Note that with your setup you can't simply load `biblatex` additionally, if you want to switch you need to follow [he guide here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864). You could help us to help you by not showing us only bits of your code, but a fully functional, yet small [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: The MWE is now on. Actually, I have found a workaround using `biblatex`, so maybe (now) the tag could be used!

Comment: As far as I can see, without an update to `footbib`, the package cannot be used with recent versions of LaTeX.