# How do I embed citations into footnotes using natbib?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, natbib

I knew citations can be embedded as footnotes in biblatex using `\footcite{}`. I encountered an error `! Undefined control sequence.`
.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \footcite
```

I tried to solve it by adding the package `biblatex`, but encountered another issue `! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.`.

How do I embed citations into footnotes using natbib?

---

This question is not duplicated with [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) as I am seeking for a solution of embedding citations into footnotes (I use the template latex using `natbib` from Cambridge for my thesis) without switching to `biblatex` (it raises other issues.).

Comment: Short answer (because of missing MWE): `\footnote{\cite{…}}`. Nevertheless, I would recommend to switch over from `natbib` to `biblatex`. This means you should remove loading `natbib` and use `biblatex` and `biber` instead (and also remove `\bibliographystyle` and replace `\bibliography` by `\addbibresource` and `printbibliography`). If you need `natbib` compatibility you can use option `natbib`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Comment: @Schweinebacke, any reason to switch to biblatex?

Comment: You want to use `\footcite` and `biblatex` provides `\footcite`. ;-) And have a look into http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `natbib` does not have a `\footcite` equivalent. There is [`footbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footbib), but I'm not even sure if its compatible with `natbib`. Other than that your best bet might be `\footnote{\cite{...}}` or a new command for that. Is there any special reason you have to use `natbib` and can't use `biblatex`?

Comment: @moewe, I use the latex template from Cambridge for my thesis and they use `natbib`. When I replace `natbib` with `biblatex`, it raises a lot of issues such as `Incompatible package 'backref'`.

Comment: Mhhh, OK. If you insist on using that template and that template insists on using `natbib` there is not a lot you can do. If `footbib` does not work for you, you need the manual approach. (Bear in mind that templates are rightfully seen critically on this site, so if you don't have to use that particular template, why not start from scratch with only the things you need and want?)

Comment: @moewe, I've just tried `footbib` and it raised `! Package footbib Error: the output routine of LaTeX changed.`. Anyway, I simply use `footnote{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`natbib` does not provide commands for citations in footnotes out of the box.

You can certainly use `\footnote{\cite{sigfridsson}}` and you can create a command for that

```
\newcommand*{\footcite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}
```

Though you might want to make it more sophisticated with handling for optional arguments if you intend to use it more often.

There used to be the `footbib` package, but according to egreg's comment on [Footbib package error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345784/35864) that is incompatible with more recent versions of LaTeX.

If you can't switch to `biblatex` (or `jurabib`) you will have to use the poor man's version I suggested above.

Comment: By way of follow-up... I recently started working on an older document that uses `natbib` and this custom command is very helpful! That said, how can I adjust the command for citations that include the page number for a citation, i.e. `\footcite[2]{sigfridsson}`?

Comment: @gravityflyer As I said, you need a more sophisticated approach. If you only care about one optional argument, something like `\NewDocumentCommand{\footcite}{om}{\footnote{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}}}` works. If you want both, you need more involved logic. (In which case I suggest you ask a new question, as it gets a bit tricky writing the required code here in the comments.)

Comment: *@moewe* Thank you! Yes, will add a new question since the suggested code `\NewDocumentCommand{\footcite}{om}{\footnote{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}}}` unfortunately isn't working for me.

Comment: Update: Successfully amended the code and got it to be fully functional! For future users, updated code can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659512/natbib-footnote-citation/659536#659536)