# Change Biblatex commands to Natbib

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am new to LaTeX and am trying to switch from `biblatex` to `natbib` because I need to use a particular `.bst` file.

I have lots of citations using `biblatex` commands so I would like to know how to automatically replace all `biblatex` commands to `natbib` commands.

For example, in my document now, I have `\textcite{someliterature}`. How can I make it to `\citet{someliterature}` without manually changing every command myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\newcommand*{\textcite}{\citet}
\newcommand*{\parencite}{\citep}
```

Should be enough for the commonly used commands `\textcite` and `\parencite`.
Depending on your `\autocite` settings you may also need

```
\newcommand*{\autocite}{\citep}
```

`\footcite` can be emulated as in [How do I embed citations into footnotes using natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357107/35864) with

```
\newcommand*{\footcite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}
```

Not all of `biblatex`'s commands have a `natbib` equivalent, though. So in some cases you may have to resort to other tricks.