# Natbib Footnote Citation

Tags: citing, footnotes, natbib

Building on the helpful suggestions offered by @moewe both [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427579/change-biblatex-commands-to-natbib?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357107/how-do-i-embed-citations-into-footnotes-using-natbib/357121?noredirect=1#comment1640835_357121), I wanted seek assistance for a more complex footnote citation command that would allow the user to include page numbers as well. Long story short, I'm helping a colleague with an old project that uses natbib.

Minimal working example as follows,

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
    author = {Author Name},
    publisher = {Publisher Co.},
    title = {Title of the Book},
    year = {2022}}
\end{filecontents}
\listfiles 

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\footcite}{om}{\footnote{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}}}

Test function of footnote citation without page number.\footcite{A01}

Test function of footnote citation with page number.\footcite[2]{A01}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the command `\NewDocumentCommand{\footcite}{om}{\footnote{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\cite{#2}}{\cite[#1]{#2}}}}` results in undefined control sequence errors.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I finally figured it out! Please see the *now* functional MWE with desired output. Also note that I added some stylistic options. I hope this helps future users in similar need!

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
    author = {Author Name},
    publisher = {Publisher Co.},
    title = {Title of the Book},
    year = {2022}}
\end{filecontents}
\listfiles 

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related command, replaces default brackets to parentheses 
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} %Citation-related command, removes default comma between author & year

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\footcite{o m}
{%
\footnote{ %
\IfNoValueTF {#1}%
{\citet{#2}}%
{\citet[#1]{#2}}%
}
}

\begin{document}

Test function of footnote citation without page number.\footcite{A01}

Test function of footnote citation with page number.\footcite[2]{A01}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```